# WPF MVVM TextBox.InputBindings equivalent for Universal Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have to write an app for a Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm using VS2015 Universal Windows app.

In my previous projects I have used the following code to bind key events:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Key="Enter" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox
```

In WinRT there's no such thing as `<TextBox.InputBindings>`. What is the equivalent of WPF MVVM's `TextBox.InputBindings` in WinRT?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not available in WinRT.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868161.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Important  Setting AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey or
>   AutomationProperties.AccessKey doesn't enable keyboard functionality.
>   It only reports to the UI Automation framework what keys should be
>   used, so that such information can be passed on to users via assistive
>   technologies. The implementation for key handling still needs to be
>   done in code, not XAML. You will still need to attach handlers for
>   KeyDown or KeyUp events on the relevant control in order to actually
>   implement the keyboard shortcut behavior in your app. Also, the
>   underline text decoration for an access key is not provided
>   automatically. You must explicitly underline the text for the specific
>   key in your mnemonic as inline Underline formatting if you wish to
>   show underlined text in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kirotab, I had my doubts but now I'm certain. 
Is there a work around I can use to tell my VM that the enter key has been pressed ?

Recently I came across this link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834227/invoke-command-when-enter-key-is-pressed-in-xaml) and the answer posted by @bitxwise was pretty usefull. Sadly I tried his method but the `FrameworkElement_KeyDown()` event is called twice for some reason when the enter key is pressed on  a textbox in my case.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, looks nice (unlike the solution that I did with code behind handling a while ago where I fired my command manually from the KeyDown handler (LoginBtn.Command.Execute(null)). As soon as I find some time I'll check it out. And for the multiple event's I had the same issue and I had to finish my task in a hurry so the quick workaround was to add additional flag that is raised when I start handling the button down and is released when I finish handling it. I'm not 100% sure what caused it but I was thinking that it's caused because of long press on the virtual keyboard.